# "File 'LoginPageProperties.json' not found" error in Amazon WorkSpaces login page

Tags: amazon-web-services, workspace

When trying to connect to Amazon WorkSpaces I am getting an error. The workspace app doesn't display login page and on checking the logs at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Amazon Web Services\Amazon WorkSpaces\logs`, I found this:

> [ERR] File 'LoginPageProperties.json' is not found

Appreciate any help to resolve this.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for Programming Q&A. You might receive a better response at: https://repost.aws/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.